# Sublime Linter 3 - PHP - Highlighting just one mistake (even if multiple exist)

Tags: php, sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin, sublimelinter

It must be really simple but I really can't find why is it doing so.

Sublimlinter -php for ST3 is highlighting only one mistake at time, even if there are others in my code. 
If I command to show all errors, I just see one error. If I delete where this error is, it will show me another one, but still like there is only this one in all the code.
If I command next or prev error, it will just stay on the one highlighted.

So the only way for me to see all the errors is to correct or delete every single error one by one, and those who use this plug in know how meticulous it is :p

Find here my user settings in SL3.

```
{
    "user": {
        "debug": true,
        "delay": 0.75,
        "error_color": "D02000",
        "gutter_theme": "",
        "gutter_theme_excludes": [],
        "lint_mode": "background",
        "linters": {
            "csslint": {
                "@disable": false,
                "args": [],
                "errors": "",
                "excludes": [],
                "ignore": "",
                "warnings": ""
            },
            "htmltidy": {
                "@disable": false,
                "args": [],
                "excludes": []
            },
            "php": {
                "@disable": false,
                "args": [],
                "excludes": []
            },
            "phpcs": {
                "@disable": false,
                "args": [],
                "excludes": [],
                "standard": "PSR2"
            },
            "phplint": {
                "@disable": false,
                "args": [],
                "excludes": []
            }
        },
        "mark_style": "outline",
        "no_column_highlights_line": false,
        "passive_warnings": false,
        "paths": {
            "linux": [],
            "osx": [],
            "windows": [
                "C:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12"
            ]
        },
        "python_paths": {
            "linux": [],
            "osx": [],
            "windows": []
        },
        "rc_search_limit": 3,
        "shell_timeout": 10,
        "show_errors_on_save": true,
        "show_marks_in_minimap": true,
        "syntax_map": {
            "html (django)": "html",
            "html (rails)": "html",
            "html 5": "html",
            "php": "html",
            "python django": "python"
        },
        "warning_color": "DDB700",
        "wrap_find": true
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to be sure, does it behave so even it the errors are in the different logical blocks?

Comment: Are these syntax errors? If so, it will stop parsing the code, because there's no way to tell if anything past that point is correct.

Comment: Yes, even if the error is in different blocks ! It does behave so even with errors such as forgotten space etc. not only syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

SublimeLinter-php is just an interface over the `php` executable, which means that if there is an error, it will stop at the first one because that's how `php` handles errors.

Wish it could show more, but it is not possible due to the executables limitations.